# Dual booting windows 8.1 and ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a lenovo laptop with windows 8.1. I wanted to use ubuntu alongside windows. Hence, i downloaded the ubuntu 14.04 iso and created a live pendrive using Universal USB installer.

I disabled secure boot and booted from the pendrive. All i get is the GNU GRUB command line version 2.X.
I don't get a GUI for the GRUB and i don't know how to boot into ubuntu from the command line.

I searched quite a few online forums but in vain. Can someone tell me how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it saying something like tty login in the command line?

Comment: nope. All i get is 'grub>'. Tells me that i can view a list of commands if a hit 'TAB'. And that it has minimal BASH-like line editing.

Comment: I think something went wrong with you installation. Put the Ubuntu Live CD and try to repair it. Maybe this is helpful: http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?152790-How-to-use-Grub2-to-boot-Linux-manually

Comment: I used different software for creating the live USB. Unetbootin and live USB creator to be specific. This time i got a GRUB to choose between trying and installing linux, but when i hit enter on either of those, i get an error saying "invalid magic number". Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help. But try to post this to AskUbuntu which is also a StackExchange site. You might get there faster a answer.

Comment: @Sriniketh - Try a different Ubuntu version. Also, burn your ISO to a real DVD and see if it'll boot. That will confirm whether the ISO is corrupt or not.

Comment: Use this guide: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html I used it today (21-05-2014) and had no trouble, i got a nice dualboot on my laptop with ubuntu and win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the Live .iso file and then burn that to disk? If so, you may want to check the official Ubuntu MD5 hash [from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) against your download. If not exactly the same, it may explain you issues. In that case re-download and try again...

All the best,
dkp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just loaded the Boot Menu(F12 on Lenovos) then booted windows from there.

After that, you can create a windows recovery (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive).

Answer (score 0):

i was finally able to do it. I used a DVD and burned the iso onto it. It worked perfectly. Though i still don't know why the flashdrive gave me that "invalid magic number" error.